# content of rel and type attribute for embedding favicon with link element

Tags: html, favicon

To embed a favicon on a webpage we use the `<link>` element. Something like this:

```
<link rel="What goes here?" type="What goes here?" href="/favicon.ico"/>
```

What value do I put in the rel and type attributes?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

```
<link rel="icon" 
     type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```

according to wikipedia the above is not supported by IE

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

this solution seems the best to me: -

```
favicon.ico located in the web site's root
```

Comment: I am not using a png image type but an ico type so what will the type attribute value be then?

Comment: good old trusty Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

would pay perticular interest to the Accessibility Header ;)